# How can I know if a node is already defined?

Tags: tikz-pgf, conditionals, nodes

I think I've seen this question before, but I can't find it. The problem is simple; before I assign a name to a node I would like to know if the name is already used.

I think when a node is created `\node (name) {label};` some macros are defined from `name`.

Comment: Upped and starred. This has bothered me for a while.

Comment: Related Question: [Checking whether or not a node has been previously defined](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

A PGF/TikZ node with the name `<name>` defines the macro `\pgf@sh@ns@<name>` (e.g. `\csname pgf@sh@ns@#1\endcsname` where `#1` is the name). This macro
defines the node shape (ns), e.g. `rectangle`. 
Other defined macros are `\pgf@sh@np@<name>` (Node Point), `\pgf@sh@nt@<name>` (Node Transformation matrix) and `\pgf@sh@pi@<name>` (node Picture Id).

You can use e.g. `\@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{<node does not exists>}{<node exists>}` to test if a node with this name got already define in the document (node are declared globally).

If you want to test if the node was already used *in the current picture*, you better test (also) the picture id if it matches the current picture id (`\pgfpictureid`, e.g. `pgfid1`, i.e. use `\ifx` for comparision).

Here some possible implementations of such macros (not tested yet):

```
\def\@nodeundefined#1{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}%
}
% or
\long\def\@nodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}

\def\@nodedefinedcurrpic#1{%   
   \expandafter\ifx\csname pgf@sh@pi@#1\endcsname\pgfpictureid
      \expandafter\@firstoftwo
   \else
      \expandafter\@secondoftwo
   \fi
}
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot the part of the name `pgf@ns@...` thanks also for the abbreviations ns, np, etc.  very useful. Do you know what is the signification of sh ? Now with your help, I look at the sources and I remark : `\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1} `.

Comment: @Altermundus: I would say `sh` stands for 'shape'. Nodes are defined mostly over their shape.

Comment: To place a node with the anchor of a given named node, the sources give : `\def\pgfpointanchor#1#2{%
  % Ok, check whether #1 is known!
  \pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}
  {\pgfutil@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@not yet positionedPGFINTERNAL#1}{%...`