# creating time line of medical history / injury history of athlete

Tags: moderntimeline

I am trying to create a timeline of an athlete medical record including on this dates of specific events and also wether the athlete was injured or not. The data will come from an sql database.
Any help would be appreciated

thanks

Doc James

Comment: This might do what you want http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61237/timeline-and-tikz

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Please post a small example so we know what sort of entries are involved and what you've tried. See also [chronology](http://ctan.org/pkg/chronology).