# What tools/libraries are available for displaying string algorithms?

Tags: tikz-pgf, strings

I would like to write up a string algorithm similar to the image shown below, but I'm not sure which tools would be best for this.

[image: string alg image]

I could use `tabular` for boxes or `tikz` to generate nodes on a grid-based system, but neither seem like the right solution for me (unless `tikz` has some packages for this). What tools are typically used to write text on a grid like this, optionally adding arrows, lines, and enclosing boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just to say it is fairly easy to program a Ti*k*Z matrix to produce something like this. All you need to do then is to enter the rows.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,row sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,
  cells={nodes={minimum width=1em,text height=1.5ex,
   /utils/exec=\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<6
   \tikzset{draw}
    \ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>2
    \tikzset{fill=gray!30}
   \fi\fi}}] (mat) {
   a & b & a & b & a & c & a & & & & &\\
   & & a & b & a & b & a & c & a & & & \\
   & & & & a & b & a & b & a & c & a & \\
   & & & & & a & b & a & b & a & c & a \\
  };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You see how that works: the positions of the cells are given by the TeX counts `\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn` and `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow`, respectively. With `/utils/exec` you can define instructions that use these counts and do something with that. Here they are used to draw boxes around the 5 left-most cells (i.e. `\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<6`) and fill the last three of them (i.e. `\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>2`).

Of course, one does not have to stop there. Here is a slightly more fancy version thereof that draws the vertical connections if the corresponding nodes exist. This is done using the `execute at end matrix` key, which has not yet found its way into the `pgfmanual` (but I suspect it will be mentioned there in the future). It also shows how you can overrule the instructions, as illustrated in the epsilon entry in which `|[draw=none,fill=none]|` makes sure that there is no box and no fill even though this the other nonempty nodes in this column have a filled box. The `foreach` keys `count` and `remember` can be found in numerous posts on this site, and are well documented in the pgf manual.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\makeatletter% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/85531
\long\def\ifnodedefined#1#2#3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \matrix[matrix of math nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,row sep=1.5ex,
  cells={nodes={minimum width=1em,text height=1.5ex,
   /utils/exec=\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn<6
   \tikzset{draw}
    \ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>2
    \tikzset{fill=gray!30}
   \fi\fi}},execute at end matrix={
    \foreach \XX in {3,...,5}
     {\foreach \YY in {1,...,\the\numexpr\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-2}
      {\ifnodedefined{mat-\YY-\XX}{\ifnodedefined{mat-\the\numexpr\YY+1\relax-\XX}{%
      \draw[densely dotted] (mat-\YY-\XX) -- (mat-\the\numexpr\YY+1\relax-\XX);
      }{}}{}} }
   }] (mat) {
   a & b & a & b & a & c & a & & & & &\\
   & & a & b & a & b & a & c & a & & & \\
   & & & & a & b & a & b & a & c & a & \\
   & & & & |[draw=none,fill=none]| \varepsilon & a & b & a & b & a & c & a \\
  };
  \path foreach \X [count=\Y,remember=\X as \LastX] in {5,3,1,0} {
  (mat.west|-mat-\Y-6) node[left]{$P_\Y$}
  \ifnum\Y>1
  (mat.east|-mat-\Y-6) node[right]{$\pi[\LastX]=\X$}
  \fi};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]