# matlab2tikz and legend location

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, legend

I have a matlab plot given below, that is converted to tikz. Let's call it myfile.tikz

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=1,
xmax=3,
ymin=1,
ymax=6,
name=plot2,
legend style={at={(0.252388795928323,0.0172119972733437)},anchor=south west,legend columns=2,draw=black,fill=white,legend cell align=left}
]
\addplot [
color=blue,
solid
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 2\\
2 4\\
3 6\\
};
\addlegendentry{This is somewhat};

\addplot [
color=green!50!black,
solid
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1\\
2 2\\
3 3\\
};
\addlegendentry{very long legend};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
at=(plot2.left of south west),
anchor=right of south east,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
width=\figurewidth,
height=\figureheight,
scale only axis,
xmin=0,
xmax=1,
ymin=0,
ymax=1,
at=(plot2.right of south east),
anchor=left of south west,
axis x line*=bottom,
axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

A minimal example using tikz would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots} % to use tikz graphics as given in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
  \newlength\figureheight
  \newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \setlength\figureheight{3.46cm} 
    \setlength\figurewidth{3.46cm} 
    \input{myfile.tikz}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

So, as seen from the resulting document, the legend of middle figure is pushing the right one out of the frame.
I wonder if there is a way to put the legend to the bottom of the figure and also not push the adjecent axis objects.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This question may be similar to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/115490/pgfplots-scale-legend-position-when-below-xlabel) but definitely not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible workaround is to use `legend to name=<labelname>` and `\ref{<labelname>}` to print the legend outside the `tikzpicture`. Change the `axis` options of the axis containing the legend entries to contain

```
legend to name=widelegend,
legend style={legend columns=2}
```

and add

```
\ref{widelegend}
```

where you want to print the legend, i.e. just after the `tikzpicture`.

Note that I reduced the size of the plots a little bit, to make them fit within the `\textwidth`.

[image]

Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots} % to use tikz graphics as given in http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \setlength\figureheight{3.2cm} 
  \setlength\figurewidth{3.2cm} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=3,
    ymin=1,
    ymax=6,
    name=plot2,
    legend to name=widelegend,
    legend style={legend columns=2}
]
\addplot [
   color=blue,
   solid
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 2\\
2 4\\
3 6\\
};
\addlegendentry{This is somewhat};

\addplot [
   color=green!50!black,
   solid
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1\\
2 2\\
3 3\\
};
\addlegendentry{very long legend};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    at=(plot2.left of south west),
    anchor=right of south east,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    at=(plot2.right of south east),
    anchor=left of south west,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\ref{widelegend}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works nicely. For externalization, use `\tikzexternaldisable\ref{widelegend}\tikzexternalenable` instead of `\ref{widelegend}`. taken from [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37471/36497)

Comment: What should I do if I want to put legend at the top right corner? @Torbjorn T.

Comment: @Khaaba For a case just like this? Something like adding `name=plot3` to the options of the third axis, and then adding `\node [right] at (plot3.north east) {\ref{widelegend}};` just before `\end{tikzpicture}`. (For a better answer, please ask a new question. More people will see it, and you have more room to state clearly what you want. You can always refer back to this question if necessary.)

Answer (score 1):

@Torbjon T., whether OP[Ali] likes it or not, I made the following changes[plz refer to % <<< ... >>> in the code: MWE] to suit my purpose and it gives me a good result. Thanks a lot for wonderful techniques that made me try different options and I found this new method:

```
%\documentclass{article} %<<<< CHANGES MADE HERE: Commented >>>>
\documentclass[preview,border=7pt]{standalone} %<<<< CHANGES MADE HERE: Added >>>>
\usepackage{pgfplots} % to use tikz graphics as given in     http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
\newlength\figureheight
\newlength\figurewidth

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \setlength\figureheight{3.2cm} 
  \setlength\figurewidth{3.2cm} 
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=1,
    xmax=3,
    ymin=1,
    ymax=6,
    name=plot2,
%    legend to name=widelegend,  %<<<< CHANGES MADE HERE: Commented >>>>
%    legend style={legend columns=2} %<<<< CHANGES MADE HERE: Commented >>>>
legend style={at={(1.1,-0.2)}} %<<<< CHANGES MADE HERE: Added >>>>
]
\addplot [
   color=blue,
   solid
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 2\\
2 4\\
3 6\\
};
\addlegendentry{This is somewhat};

\addplot [
   color=green!50!black,
   solid
]
table[row sep=crcr]{
1 1\\
2 2\\
3 3\\
};
\addlegendentry{very long legend};

\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    at=(plot2.left of south west),
    anchor=right of south east,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[%
    width=\figurewidth,
    height=\figureheight,
    scale only axis,
    xmin=0,
    xmax=1,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=1,
    at=(plot2.right of south east),
    anchor=left of south west,
    axis x line*=bottom,
    axis y line*=left
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
%\ref{widelegend}%<<<< CHANGES MADE HERE: Commented >>>>
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I did not use the three commands:

```
legend to name=widelegend,
legend style={legend columns=2}
\ref{widelegend}
```

rather used one command:

```
legend style={at={(1.1,-0.2)}}
```

by manually specifying the location of the legend position.

[image]

Comment: Works fine as long as the legend entries are short enough. For example, try changing the first legend entry to `\addlegendentry{This is a somewhat extremely long legend-thingy.};`.