# Tikz fit variable number of nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, fit

I would like to draw a rectangle or ellipse over some nodes I am drawing with tikz.

I know how to do that if the number of nodes is fixed: I just enumerate them.

I was wondering if there is a way to do that if I have a variable number of nodes?

Currently I use something like this:

```
     \node[draw,dotted,fit=(V1) (V2)] {};
```

But I have multiple nodes that I would like to fit in, and their number is given by a variable. Is there a work around this?
Ideally I would like something like this, that enumerates trough all nodes

```
\node[draw,dotted,fit=(V1) .. (V\numvis)] {};
```

Because of the layout of my nodes I can actually just use:

```
\node[draw,dotted,fit=(V1) (V\numvis)] {};
```

But I am interested in the more general way, so that I have something in case I change layouts.

Thanks!

Here is the complete working code:

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\def\layersep{2cm} % Gap between visible & hidden units
\def\numvis{8} % Number if visible units
\def\numhid{5} % Number of hidden units
\def\numhidsnd{5}
\def\numhidthrd{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=\layersep,
    line/.style={shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth},
    downarrow/.style={<-,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth, thick,},
    uparrow/.style={->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth, thick, color=red},
    doublearrow/.style={<->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth, thick},
    surround/.style={draw=blue, thick, dotted, rounded corners},
    ]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=21pt,inner sep=0pt];
    \tikzstyle{visible neuron}=[neuron];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron];
    \tikzstyle{annot}=[text width=10em];

    % Iterate over visible units
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\numvis}
        \node[visible neuron] (V\name) at (\y,0) {};

    % Iterate over hidden units
    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\numhid}
        % Calculate the appropriate offset for the hidden unit based on the
        % number of visible units.
        \pgfmathparse{\y + (\numvis - \numhid) * 0.5}
        \node[hidden neuron] (H\name) at (\pgfmathresult, \layersep) {};

     \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\numhidsnd}
        % Calculate the appropriate offset for the hidden unit based on the
        % number of visible units.
        \pgfmathparse{\y + (\numhid - \numhidsnd) * 0.5}
        \node[hidden neuron] (H2\name) at (\pgfmathresult + 1.5, 2 * \layersep) {};

    \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\numhidthrd}
        % Calculate the appropriate offset for the hidden unit based on the
        % number of visible units.
        \pgfmathparse{\y + (\numhidsnd - \numhidthrd) * 0.5}
        \node[hidden neuron] (H3\name) at (\pgfmathresult + 1.5, 3 * \layersep) {};

      \node[surround, dotted,fit=(V1)  (V\numvis)] (allvis) {};
      \node[surround, fit=(H1)  (H\numhid)] (allhid) {};
      \node[surround, fit=(H21)  (H2\numhidsnd)] (allhid2) {};
      \node[surround, fit=(H31)  (H3\numhidthrd)] (allhid3) {};

      \draw[uparrow] (allvis) -- (allhid);
      \draw[uparrow] (allhid) -- (allhid2);
      \draw[downarrow] (allvis) -- (allhid);
      \draw[downarrow] (allhid) -- (allhid2);

      \draw[doublearrow] (allhid2) -- (allhid3);

      \node[annot,left of=V1, node distance=1.5cm] (hl) {Visible layer};
      \node[annot,  above of=hl] (a) {Hidden layer};
      \node[annot, above of=a] (b){Hidden layer};
      \node[annot, above of=b] (c) {Hidden layer};

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Generative versus recognition weights in a DBN.}
\label{fig:rbm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the `foreach` syntax, you can easely discribe the nodes you want to fit:

```
`\foreach \i in {1,...,5,9,\start,...,\end}
```

for example. \start and \end and some other are dynamicaly calculated.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \i in {1,...,25} {%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RandX}{(rand*5 + 1) - 2.5} ;
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\RandY}{(rand*5 + 1) - 2.5} ;
    \node (V\i) at (\RandX,\RandY) {\i} ;
    }

\xdef\Loop{}
\foreach \n in {1,2,4} {\xdef\Loop{\Loop(V\n)} }

\node[draw=red,fit=\Loop] {};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You may apply the following `auto fit` option to each special node. Its argument is the name of a collection of special nodes to fit (and the name of the resulting node).

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}

\makeatletter
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37713
\def\@nodeundefined#1{\@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}}
%
\tikzset{auto fit/.style={append after command={
      \pgfextra{
        \begin{pgfinterruptpath}
          \@nodeundefined{#1}{
            \node[fit=(\tikzlastnode),inner sep=0,line width=0](#1){};
          }{
            \node[fit=(#1)(\tikzlastnode),inner sep=0,line width=0](#1){};
          }
        \end{pgfinterruptpath}
      }}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[font=\small,auto fit=a] (V1) at ({random(0,10)},{random(0,10)}) {1} ;
  \node[font=\small,auto fit=b] (V2) at ({random(0,10)},{random(0,10)}) {2} ;
  \node[font=\small,auto fit=a] (V3) at ({random(0,10)},{random(0,10)}) {3} ;
  \node[font=\small,auto fit=b] (V4) at ({random(0,10)},{random(0,10)}) {4} ;
  \node[font=\small,auto fit=a] (V5) at ({random(0,10)},{random(0,10)}) {5} ;

  \node[draw=blue,fit=(a)]{};
  \node[draw=red,fit=(b)]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly then you want to draw a rectangle around nodes. All you have to do it to draw the nodes first, and then draw a rectangle using the corners of the picture's bounding box.

Also you can group your nodes into scopes, give the scopes name and reference them by their names.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Create your nodes first
    \node (n1) at (0, 0) {n1};
    \node (n2) at (5, 3) {n2};
    % ...
    \node (nm) at (-2, -2) {nm};

    % After drawing the nodes, you can enclose
    % them into a rectangle using the bounding
    % box of the already drawn nodes
    \draw (current bounding box.north west) rectangle
        (current bounding box.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Create your nodes first
    \node (n1) at (0, 0) {n1};
    \node (n2) at (5, 3) {n2};
    % ...
    \node (nm) at (-2, -2) {nm};

    % After drawing the nodes, you can enclose
    % them into a rectangle using the bounding
    % box of the already drawn nodes
    % 
    % Note: this rectangle will leave 0.5cm space
    % between the nodes and the sides of the rectangle
    % (the calc tikz library was loaded for this)
    \draw[color=red] ($(current bounding box.north west) + (-0.5, 0.5)$)
        rectangle ($(current bounding box.south east) + (0.5, -0.5)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Create your nodes inside scopes and give names to the scopes
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=nodegroup1]
        \node (n1) at (0, 0) {n1};
        \node (n2) at (1, 1) {n2};
        % ...
        \node (nk) at (1, -1) {nk};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=nodegroup2]
        \node (m1) at (3, 0) {m1};
        \node (m2) at (4, 1) {m2};
        % ...
        \node (ml) at (4, -1) {ml};
    \end{scope}

    % Now you can reference the bounding boxes of the scopes with their names
    \draw[color=blue] ($(nodegroup1.north west) + (-0.5, 0.5)$) rectangle
        ($(nodegroup1.south east) + (0.5, -0.5)$);

    \draw[color=green] ($(nodegroup2.north west) + (-0.5, 0.5)$) rectangle
        ($(nodegroup2.south east) + (0.5, -0.5)$);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Your MWE with using scopes for grouping:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, matrix, chains, positioning, decorations.pathreplacing, arrows, calc}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\def\layersep{2cm} % Gap between visible & hidden units
\def\numvis{8} % Number if visible units
\def\numhid{5} % Number of hidden units
\def\numhidsnd{5}
\def\numhidthrd{4}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=\layersep,
    line/.style={shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth},
    downarrow/.style={<-,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth, thick,},
    uparrow/.style={->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth, thick, color=red},
    doublearrow/.style={<->,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt,>=stealth, thick},
    %surround/.style={draw=blue, thick, dotted, rounded corners},
    surround/.style={color=blue, thick, dotted, rounded corners}
    ]
    \tikzstyle{neuron}=[circle,fill=black!25,minimum size=21pt,inner sep=0pt];
    \tikzstyle{visible neuron}=[neuron];
    \tikzstyle{hidden neuron}=[neuron];
    \tikzstyle{annot}=[text width=10em];

    % Iterate over visible units
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=group1]
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\numvis}
            \node[visible neuron] (V\name) at (\y,0) {};
    \end{scope}

    % Iterate over hidden units
    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=group2]
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\numhid}
            % Calculate the appropriate offset for the hidden unit based on the
            % number of visible units.
            \pgfmathparse{\y + (\numvis - \numhid) * 0.5}
            \node[hidden neuron] (H\name) at (\pgfmathresult, \layersep) {};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=group3]
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\numhidsnd}
            % Calculate the appropriate offset for the hidden unit based on the
            % number of visible units.
            \pgfmathparse{\y + (\numhid - \numhidsnd) * 0.5}
            \node[hidden neuron] (H2\name) at (\pgfmathresult + 1.5, 2 * \layersep) {};
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[local bounding box=group4]
        \foreach \name / \y in {1,...,\numhidthrd}
            % Calculate the appropriate offset for the hidden unit based on the
            % number of visible units.
            \pgfmathparse{\y + (\numhidsnd - \numhidthrd) * 0.5}
            \node[hidden neuron] (H3\name) at (\pgfmathresult + 1.5, 3 * \layersep) {};
    \end{scope}

    \draw[surround] ($(group1.north west) + (-2.5pt, 2.5pt)$) rectangle
        ($(group1.south east) + (2.5pt, -2.5pt)$);
    \draw[surround] ($(group2.north west) + (-2.5pt, 2.5pt)$) rectangle
        ($(group2.south east) + (2.5pt, -2.5pt)$);
    \draw[surround] ($(group3.north west) + (-2.5pt, 2.5pt)$) rectangle
        ($(group3.south east) + (2.5pt, -2.5pt)$);
    \draw[surround] ($(group4.north west) + (-2.5pt, 2.5pt)$) rectangle
        ($(group4.south east) + (2.5pt, -2.5pt)$);

    \draw[latex-latex] ($(group1.north) + (0, 3.5pt)$) --
        ($(group2.south) + (0, -3.5pt)$);
    \draw[latex-latex] ($(group2.north) + (0, 3.5pt)$) --
        ($(group3.south) + (0, -3.5pt)$);
    \draw[latex-latex] ($(group3.north) + (0, 3.5pt)$) --
        ($(group4.south) + (0, -3.5pt)$);

    \node[annot, left of=V1, node distance=1.5cm] (hl) {Visible layer};
    \node[annot, above of=hl] (a) {Hidden layer};
    \node[annot, above of=a] (b){Hidden layer};
    \node[annot, above of=b] (c) {Hidden layer};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Generative versus recognition weights in a DBN.}
\label{fig:rbm}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: But this would work if I want to select all of the nodes. What if I want to select only some of them?

Comment: @elaRosca You can use scopes to enclose your nodes. Give names to the scopes and then you can reference them by their names. I edited the answer and added an example how to do this.