# How to include a date in Timeline?

Tags: timeline

When I compile the following piece of code, I obtain a nice timeline in a short document. But, when I try to compile the same piece of code into a longer document (a 440 pages thesis), a specific date does not appear on my timeline as illustrated in this screenshot: [image] I observed that the problem appears when I have two timelines in my document. One only does not produce that error. Can you help me to fix that? Thanks!

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
           twoside=semi,%
           headings=small,%
           chapterprefix=true,%
           listof=flat]%
{scrbook}


\usepackage{chronosys}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TIMELINE%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{timeline}[6]{%
    % #1 is startyear
    % #2 is tlendyear
% #3 is yearcolumnwidth
% #4 is rulecolumnwidth
% #5 is entrycolumnwidth
% #6 is timelineheight

\newcommand{\startyear}{#1}
\newcommand{\tlendyear}{#2}

\newcommand{\yearcolumnwidth}{#3}
\newcommand{\rulecolumnwidth}{#4}
\newcommand{\entrycolumnwidth}{#5}
\newcommand{\timelineheight}{#6}

\newcommand{\templength}{}

\newcommand{\entrycounter}{0}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined
\long\def\ifnodedefined##1##2##3{%
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@##1}{##3}{##2}%
}

\newcommand{\ifnodeundefined}[2]{%
    \ifnodedefined{##1}{}{##2}
}

\newcommand{\drawtimeline}{%
    \draw[timelinerule] (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, 0pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, -\timelineheight);
    \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -10pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -10pt);
    \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -\timelineheight+15pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -\timelineheight+15pt);

    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
    \node[year] (year-\startyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\startyear};

    \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
    \node[year] (year-\tlendyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\tlendyear};
}

\newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
    % #1 is the year
    % #2 is the entry text

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

    \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
    \else%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
    \fi

    \ifnodeundefined{year-##1}{%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
        \node[year] (year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {##1};
    }

    \draw ($(year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
}

\newcommand{\plainentry}[2]{% plainentry won't print date in the timeline
    % #1 is the year
    % #2 is the entry text

    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

    \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
    \else%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
    \fi

    \ifnodeundefined{invisible-year-##1}{%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
        \node[year] (invisible-year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {};
    }

    \draw ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{entry} = [%
        align=left,%
        text width=\entrycolumnwidth,%
        node distance=10mm,%
        anchor=west]
    \tikzstyle{year} = [anchor=east]
    \tikzstyle{timelinerule} = [%
        draw,%
        decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{latex'}}},%
        postaction={decorate},%
        shorten >=0.4pt]

    \drawtimeline
}
{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \let\startyear\@undefined
    \let\tlendyear\@undefined
    \let\yearcolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\rulecolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\entrycolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\timelineheight\@undefined
    \let\entrycounter\@undefined
    \let\ifnodedefined\@undefined
    \let\ifnodeundefined\@undefined
    \let\drawtimeline\@undefined
    \let\entry\@undefined
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%FIN TIMELINE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}


\pagestyle{headings}



\begin{table}[!]


\begin{timeline}{2014}{2017}{2cm}{2.5cm}{10cm}{5cm}
\entry{2014}{Octobre. Enregistrement}
\entry{2014}{Novembre. Transcription}
\entry{2015}{Mars. Travail}
\entry{2016}{Avril. Reprise}
\entry{2017}{Septembre. Fin}
\end{timeline}

\caption{Chronologie}

\end{table}


\begin{table}[!]


\begin{timeline}{2014}{2017}{2cm}{2.5cm}{10cm}{5cm}
\entry{2014}{Octobre. Enregistrement}
\entry{2014}{Novembre. Transcription}
\entry{2015}{Mars. Travail}
\entry{2016}{Avril. Reprise}
\entry{2017}{Septembre. Fin}
\end{timeline}

\caption{Chronologie}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: do you have all these blank lines in original? I doubt it, here `timeline` environment definition is wrong because of the blank line between the two `{...}` giant constructs.

Comment: anyway, as you said, this compiles fine (once the source code is corrected as per my previous comment), hence it is hard to guess what's wrong. Edit: there is some funny `invisible-year-...` business going on. Are you sure the 2015 did not become "invisible" in this sens from some other code in your big document?

Comment: @jfbu What would be the right code?

Comment: hard to help if all you post is something which does not display the problem you describe...

Answer (score 2):

The code posted here doesn't compile for me and the `\timeline` macro is different to the original source, which is here: [How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197140/) I didn't try to find where it is different.

I replaced the timeline code that was posted with the code from the original source and provide two examples. The first example shows the years for each timeline entry. This can be done using the `\entry` macro. The second example shows the addition of timeline entries, but without displaying the year. This is done with the `\plainentry` macro.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,%
           twoside=semi,%
           headings=small,%
           chapterprefix=true,%
           listof=flat]%
{scrbook}


%\usepackage{chronosys}
\usepackage{verbatim}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%TIMELINE%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197140
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{timeline}[6]
{
    % #1 is startyear
    % #2 is tlendyear
    % #3 is yearcolumnwidth
    % #4 is rulecolumnwidth
    % #5 is entrycolumnwidth
    % #6 is timelineheight

    \newcommand{\startyear}{#1}
    \newcommand{\tlendyear}{#2}

    \newcommand{\yearcolumnwidth}{#3}
    \newcommand{\rulecolumnwidth}{#4}
    \newcommand{\entrycolumnwidth}{#5}
    \newcommand{\timelineheight}{#6}

    \newcommand{\templength}{}

    \newcommand{\entrycounter}{0}

    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined
    \long\def\ifnodedefined##1##2##3{%
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@##1}{##3}{##2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\ifnodeundefined}[2]{%
        \ifnodedefined{##1}{}{##2}
    }

    \newcommand{\drawtimeline}{%
        \draw[timelinerule] (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, 0pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, -\timelineheight);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -10pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -10pt);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -\timelineheight+15pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -\timelineheight+15pt);

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\startyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\startyear};

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\tlendyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\tlendyear};
    }

    \newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {##1};
        }

        \draw ($(year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \newcommand{\plainentry}[2]{% plainentry won't print date in the timeline
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{invisible-year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (invisible-year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {};
        }

        \draw ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{entry} = [%
    align=left,%
    text width=\entrycolumnwidth,%
    node distance=11mm,%
    anchor=west]
    \tikzstyle{year} = [anchor=east]
    \tikzstyle{timelinerule} = [%
    draw,%
    decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{latex'}}},%
    postaction={decorate},%
    shorten >=0.4pt]

    \drawtimeline
}
{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \let\startyear\@undefined
    \let\tlendyear\@undefined
    \let\yearcolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\rulecolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\entrycolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\timelineheight\@undefined
    \let\entrycounter\@undefined
    \let\ifnodedefined\@undefined
    \let\ifnodeundefined\@undefined
    \let\drawtimeline\@undefined
    \let\entry\@undefined
}
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%FIN TIMELINE%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{headings}
%\begin{table}[!]

Using \verb|\entry| only 

\begin{timeline}{2014}{2017}{2cm}{2.5cm}{10cm}{5cm}
    \entry{2014}{Octobre.  Enregistrement}
    \entry{2014}{Novembre.  Transcription}
    \entry{2015}{Mars. Travail}
    \entry{2016}{Avril. Reprise}
    \entry{2017}{Septembre. Fin}
\end{timeline}

\bigskip

Using \verb|\plainentry| to blank the years for some timeline entries

\bigskip

\begin{timeline}{2014}{2017}{2cm}{2.5cm}{10cm}{5cm}
\entry{2014}{Octobre.  Enregistrement}
\entry{2014}{Novembre.  Transcription}
\plainentry{2015}{Mars. Travail}
\plainentry{2016}{Avril. Reprise}
\entry{2017}{Septembre. Fin}
\end{timeline}

%\caption{Chronologie}

%\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand. So, how could I use only \entry?

Comment: Replace everything in your code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` with the timeline code I posted here. I also suggest don't load the `chronosys` package. You aren't using it.

Comment: I did it, but it does not work. Was the original code designed in order to set two timeline, the first with \entry, the second with \plainentry? If it was the case, shouldn't have I to remove \plainentry command from the code?

Comment: Each timeline is an environment. It starts with \begin{timeline} and ends with \end{timeline}. You can have as many as is required in the document. The code between \makeatletter and \makeatother creates each timeline. Each timeline entry can either include or omit the year, depending on whether the entry was added with \entry or \plainentry, respectively. My guess is you have a timeline environment that is using \plainentry. Try searching for \plainentry, because that is what is producing entries with blank years.

Comment: Sorry, I understood that what I am looking for is a single timeline environment with only a \entry command, but I can't get to find how to remove that \plainentry in my document.

Comment: Q1. Do you have a timeline environment that includes a timeline entry written as \plainentry{year}{something}? Q2. If you can find that entry, change it to \entry{year}{something}.

Comment: Thanks. As you can see above, there is only this piece of code: \newcommand{\plainentry}[2], nothing else I could change.

Comment: @domi Only you have access to the code which produces the problem you report. You've posted code which (1) you say doesn't produce any problem at all and (2) which others find produces a problem, though not the one you report. Presumably, therefore, both the solution to the problem others find with the posted code and the problem you find with the non-posted code lie somewhere in the complement of the intersection of the subset of non-posted code which coincides with the posted code and the totality of the non-posted code or, else, with its interaction with that posted. Do you see the problem?