# Is it possible to erase a TiKz node from the memory?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Given Martin Scharrer's nice answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined?noredirect=1&lq=1), I am wondering if one can "undefine" nodes. That is, I'd like to know of there is a command, say, `\undefine{mynode}` after which Martin Scharrer's command would return undefined. Here is an illustration.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\istikznodedefined}[1]{%
\@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{\fbox{Sorry, I don't know about node #1!}}{%
\fbox{Sure, I node where node #1 is!}}}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\erasenode}[1]{\fbox{I can't erase node #1 yet}} % This is the command that I'd like to learn about (or create).

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture] \node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}
\istikznodedefined{a}

\lipsum[1]
\tikzmark{a}

\istikznodedefined{a}

\lipsum[2]

\erasenode{a}

Here I'd like the command \verb|\istikznodedefined{a}| to return 
\begin{quote}
\fbox{Sorry, I don't know about node a!}
\end{quote}
but I don't know how to achieve this.

The real reason for asking this is that, if this worked, one could switch
annotations on and off with e.g.\ \texttt{eso-pic}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Related/duplicate? [Is there a way to forget node names between TikZ pictures?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/178778)

Comment: @AlanMunn Yes. Thanks! Should I erase my question?

Comment: No, I'll vote to close it as a duplicate, and then you can agree with that close vote and the two questions will be linked.

Comment: @Circumscribe Yes, that's the plan.

Comment: @Circumscribe No worries, I have copied it.