# vertical timeline tikz clash with beamer poster

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamerposter

This vertical timeline using tikz looks great in an article but in a beamer poster the line spacing is miscalculated.  The tikz code is from  [szantaii's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154558/) to the question [High level macros and environments based on Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52394/high-level-macros-and-environments-based-on-tikz), incorporated in this working example:

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerposter}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{timeline}[6]{%
    % #1 is startyear
    % #2 is tlendyear
    % #3 is yearcolumnwidth
    % #4 is rulecolumnwidth
    % #5 is entrycolumnwidth
    % #6 is timelineheight

    \newcommand{\startyear}{#1}
    \newcommand{\tlendyear}{#2}

    \newcommand{\yearcolumnwidth}{#3}
    \newcommand{\rulecolumnwidth}{#4}
    \newcommand{\entrycolumnwidth}{#5}
    \newcommand{\timelineheight}{#6}

    \newcommand{\templength}{}

    \newcommand{\entrycounter}{0}

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined
    \long\def\ifnodedefined##1##2##3{%
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@##1}{##3}{##2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\ifnodeundefined}[2]{%
        \ifnodedefined{##1}{}{##2}
    }

    \newcommand{\drawtimeline}{%
        \draw[timelinerule] (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, 0pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, -\timelineheight);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -10pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -10pt);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -\timelineheight+15pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -\timelineheight+15pt);

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\startyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\startyear};

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\tlendyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\tlendyear};
    }

    \newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {##1};
        }

        \draw ($(year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \newcommand{\plainentry}[2]{% plainentry won't print date in the timeline
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{invisible-year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (invisible-year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {};
        }

        \draw ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{entry} = [%
            align=left,%
            text width=\entrycolumnwidth,%
            node distance=10mm,%
            anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{year} = [anchor=east]
        \tikzstyle{timelinerule} = [%
            draw,%
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{latex'}}},%
            postaction={decorate},%
            shorten >=0.4pt]

        \drawtimeline
}
{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \let\startyear\@undefined
    \let\tlendyear\@undefined
    \let\yearcolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\rulecolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\entrycolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\timelineheight\@undefined
    \let\entrycounter\@undefined
    \let\ifnodedefined\@undefined
    \let\ifnodeundefined\@undefined
    \let\drawtimeline\@undefined
    \let\entry\@undefined
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{timeline}{1940}{2020}{5cm}{2cm}{20cm}{15cm}

\plainentry{1941}{1941 this timeline entry is long enough to continue on a second line}
\plainentry{1946}{1946 this entry gets stepped on}
\plainentry{1947}{1947 this entry is long enough to continue on a second line and then even a third line it is quite the run-on entry that runs on and on and on do you see it run on?}
\plainentry{1947}{This is another entry for the same year}
\plainentry{1948}{1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 }
\plainentry{1951}{1951 some text}
\entry{1955}{1955 some other text}
\entry{1960}{1960 yet more text}
\entry{1970}{1970 and still more}
\entry{2015}{2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 }
\plainentry{2018}{2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018}

\end{timeline}

\end{document}
```

And the result:

[image: A vertical timeline with overlapped lines]

Comment: What does '@szantaii' mean? If that code has a source, can you provide a link?

Comment: An obvious workaround is to typeset the timeline separately, then load it from a PDF into the poster.  But I will make more timelines so fixing this interaction would be better.

Comment: Okay, I figured out how to add the link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE. You just need to set the `node distance` to an appropriate amount to get the right spacing of your labels. I made it `node distance=20mm`.  I added the timeline to a two-column frame and it seems to be fine. You will need to play with node distance and the length of the timeline to suit your particular needs.

[image]

```
%\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{geometry}

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[size=custom,height=150,width=90,scale=1]{beamerposter}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{timeline}[6]
{
    % #1 is startyear
    % #2 is tlendyear
    % #3 is yearcolumnwidth
    % #4 is rulecolumnwidth
    % #5 is entrycolumnwidth
    % #6 is timelineheight

    \newcommand{\startyear}{#1}
    \newcommand{\tlendyear}{#2}

    \newcommand{\yearcolumnwidth}{#3}
    \newcommand{\rulecolumnwidth}{#4}
    \newcommand{\entrycolumnwidth}{#5}
    \newcommand{\timelineheight}{#6}

    \newcommand{\templength}{}

    \newcommand{\entrycounter}{0}

    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined
    % http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined
    \long\def\ifnodedefined##1##2##3{%
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@##1}{##3}{##2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\ifnodeundefined}[2]{%
        \ifnodedefined{##1}{}{##2}
    }

    \newcommand{\drawtimeline}{%
        \draw[timelinerule] (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, 0pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, -\timelineheight);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -10pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -10pt);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -\timelineheight+15pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -\timelineheight+15pt);

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\startyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\startyear};

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\tlendyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\tlendyear};
    }

    \newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {##1};
        }

        \draw ($(year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \newcommand{\plainentry}[2]{% plainentry won't print date in the timeline
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{invisible-year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (invisible-year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {};
        }

        \draw ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tikzstyle{entry} = [%
    align=left,%
    text width=\entrycolumnwidth,%
    node distance=20mm,%     <-- Adjust this to get wider spacing of the labels
    anchor=west]
    \tikzstyle{year} = [anchor=east]
    \tikzstyle{timelinerule} = [%
    draw,%
    decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{latex'}}},%
    postaction={decorate},%
    shorten >=0.4pt]

    \drawtimeline
}
{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \let\startyear\@undefined
    \let\tlendyear\@undefined
    \let\yearcolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\rulecolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\entrycolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\timelineheight\@undefined
    \let\entrycounter\@undefined
    \let\ifnodedefined\@undefined
    \let\ifnodeundefined\@undefined
    \let\drawtimeline\@undefined
    \let\entry\@undefined
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{}

  \begin{columns}[t]

    \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{FOOBAR}
         \begin{timeline}{1940}{2020}{5cm}{2cm}{20cm}{20cm}

         \plainentry{1941}{1941 this timeline entry is long enough to continue on a second line}
         \plainentry{1946}{1946 this entry gets stepped on}
         \plainentry{1947}{1947 this entry is long enough to continue on a second line and then even a third line it is quite the run-on entry that runs on and on and on do you see it run on?}
         \plainentry{1947}{This is another entry for the same year}
         \plainentry{1948}{1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 1948 }
         \plainentry{1951}{1951 some text}
         \entry{1955}{1955 some other text}
         \entry{1960}{1960 yet more text}
         \entry{1970}{1970 and still more}
         \entry{2015}{2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 2015 }
         \plainentry{2018}{2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018 2018}

         \end{timeline}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

    \begin{column}{.45\linewidth}
      \begin{block}{FOOBAR}
       foobar
      \end{block}
    \end{column}

  \end{columns}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see.  Thanks!  The node distance (label depth) is explicit and equal for all labels, regardless of the number of lines of text in the label.  The node distance could be calculated.

Comment: Yes, the node distance is explicitly set here: `\node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};`. You need a different solution to stack the nodes without spaces. See @Zarko's first solution here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508240/. It puts the labels on a `chain`. TorbjørnT.'s answer also updates the timeline code you used to replace deprecated syntax.

Comment: Oh, super!  Thank you.  That Q&A thread is new to me or I would not have started this one.  I need a few more rep points before I can comment, vote, or do anything much over there.