# Vertical timeline latex

Tags: tikz-pgf, timeline

Given the vertical timelines in "[How can you create a vertical timeline?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196794/how-can-you-create-a-vertical-timeline)" and specifically [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197447/223558), would it be possible to make the distance between points scale with their numerical distance?
E.g. points 2000, 2005 will be half as far apart as 2010,2020

`from the second link:`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}

% code by Andrew:
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28452/13304
\makeatletter
\let\matamp=&
\catcode`\&=13
\makeatletter
\def&{\iftikz@is@matrix
  \pgfmatrixnextcell
  \else
  \matamp
  \fi}
\makeatother

\newcounter{lines}
\def\endlr{\stepcounter{lines}\\}

\newcounter{vtml}
\setcounter{vtml}{0}

\newif\ifvtimelinetitle
\newif\ifvtimebottomline
\tikzset{description/.style={
  column 2/.append style={#1}
 },
 timeline color/.store in=\vtmlcolor,
 timeline color=red!80!black,
 timeline color st/.style={fill=\vtmlcolor,draw=\vtmlcolor},
 use timeline header/.is if=vtimelinetitle,
 use timeline header=false,
 add bottom line/.is if=vtimebottomline,
 add bottom line=false,
 timeline title/.store in=\vtimelinetitle,
 timeline title={},
 line offset/.store in=\lineoffset,
 line offset=4pt,
}

\NewEnviron{vtimeline}[1][]{%
\setcounter{lines}{1}%
\stepcounter{vtml}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[column 1/.style={anchor=east},
 column 2/.style={anchor=west},
 text depth=0pt,text height=1ex,
 row sep=1ex,
 column sep=1em,
 #1
]
\matrix(vtimeline\thevtml)[matrix of nodes]{\BODY};
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\endmtx{\thelines-1}
\path[timeline color st] 
($(vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-1-2.north west)$)--
($(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-1.south east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\endmtx-2.south west)$);
\foreach \x in {1,...,\endmtx}{
 \node[circle,timeline color st, inner sep=0.15pt, draw=white, thick] 
 (vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x) at 
 ($(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-1.east)!0.5!(vtimeline\thevtml-\x-2.west)$){};
 \draw[timeline color st](vtimeline\thevtml-c-\x.west)--++(-3pt,0);
 }
 \ifvtimelinetitle%
  \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north west)--
  ([yshift=\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.north east);
  \node[anchor=west,yshift=16pt,font=\large]
   at (vtimeline\thevtml-1-1.north west) 
   {\textsc{Timeline \thevtml}: \textit{\vtimelinetitle}};
 \else%
  \relax%
 \fi%
 \ifvtimebottomline%
   \draw[timeline color st]([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south west)--
  ([yshift=-\lineoffset]vtimeline\thevtml.south east);
 \else%
   \relax%
 \fi%
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{vtimeline}[timeline color=cyan!80!blue, add bottom line, line offset=2pt]
1947 & AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones\endlr
1968 & Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'\endlr
1971 & Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator\endlr
1973 & First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper\endlr
1978 & Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy\endlr
1981 & Osborne 1 Portable Computer\endlr
1982 & Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop\endlr
1983 & TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC\endlr
1984 & Psion Organiser Handheld Computer\endlr
1991 & Psion Series 3 Minicomputer\endlr
\end{vtimeline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I used the solution here: [vertical timeline tikz clash with beamer poster](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511661/vertical-timeline-tikz-clash-with-beamer-poster)

Comment: Honestly I wish I could combine the two.  Torbjørn T's is prettier but I wish I could manipulate the lines for when entries are very close to one another.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That specific approach uses a `\matrix` to lay out the timeline, so it's not straightforward to adjust the row spacing as you want to. A different approach would be to use `pgfplots` and make the timeline with an actual plot. The text can be added with `nodes near coords`.

I haven't tried wrapping this in a macro/environment as in the post you refer to, but I can try doing that tomorrow, if you want to.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{charter}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{
year ; label
1947 ; AT and T Bell Labs develop the idea of cellular phones 
1968 ; Xerox Palo Alto Research Centre envisage the `Dynabook'
1971 ; Busicom 'Handy-LE' Calculator 
1973 ; First mobile handset invented by Martin Cooper 
1978 ; Parker Bros. Merlin Computer Toy 
1981 ; Osborne 1 Portable Computer 
1982 ; Grid Compass 1100 Clamshell Laptop 
1983 ; TRS-80 Model 100 Portable PC 
1984 ; Psion Organiser Handheld Computer 
1991 ; Psion Series 3 Minicomputer
}\datatable


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  y dir=reverse,
  footnotesize,
  hide x axis,
  axis y line=left,
  axis line style={-, draw=none},
  ytick=data,
  xmin=0.99,
  clip=false,
  nodes near coords,
  nodes near coords align=right,
  point meta=explicit symbolic,
  yticklabel style={
    /pgf/number format/set thousands separator={},
    inner sep=1pt
    },
  scale only axis,
  width=1mm,
  height=15cm,
  tick align=outside,
  every tick/.append style={thin, cyan}
  ]
  
  \addplot [mark=*,cyan,mark size=2, shorten <=-2mm, shorten >=-2mm, thick] table[y index=0, x expr=1, meta=label] {\datatable};

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It's pretty near perfect for what I'm looking for.  And it helps me wrap my head around the enigma that is tikz/pgf, so thanks a million (:
My only question(s): is there a way to extend a line like @Una's answer for only *some* entries (i.e. when two entries are so close to one another that they'd overlap)?  And is there a way to break long entries into two lines (i.e. 1 point but 2 right-hand line)?  I'm using this for a daily 24h log, and entries are often within 5 minutes of each other.  Which even with the timeline spanning the full vertical height of the page still overlaps.

Comment: I'll just mark it as solved in any event

Comment: @SKNB For line breaking, if you add `nodes near coords style={anchor=mid west, align=left},` to the `axis` options you can use ```\\``` in the data file to add line breaks manually. Alternatively, `text width=8cm` (or some other suitable length) instead of `align=left`, for automatic line breaking. Don't have a solution for the other problem, it's probably possible, but would take some work.