# How do I adjust tikz timeline to poster template?

Tags: tikz-arrows, beamerposter, timeline

this is my first time ever trying to use complex templates that other people have made and this is giving me a problem.

So what I'm trying to do is to add a timeline (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197140) to a poster template (http://www.nathanieljohnston.com/2009/08/latex-poster-template/).

Unfortunately, what I get it is something like this:

[image]

This is the latex code:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}           % allows us to import images
\usepackage{tikz}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column width and poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% The separation I chose is 0.024 and I want 4 columns
% Then set onecolwid to be (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be 2*onecolwid + sepwid = 0.464
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in}
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth}
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth}
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth}
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\usepackage{exscale}

%==============================================================================
% build the poster timeline
%==============================================================================

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{timeline}[6]{

    \newcommand{\startyear}{#1}
    \newcommand{\tlendyear}{#2}

    \newcommand{\yearcolumnwidth}{#3}
    \newcommand{\rulecolumnwidth}{#4}
    \newcommand{\entrycolumnwidth}{#5}
    \newcommand{\timelineheight}{#6}

    \newcommand{\templength}{}

    \newcommand{\entrycounter}{0}

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined
    \long\def\ifnodedefined##1##2##3{%
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@##1}{##3}{##2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\ifnodeundefined}[2]{%
        \ifnodedefined{##1}{}{##2}
    }

    \newcommand{\drawtimeline}{%
        \draw[timelinerule] (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, 0pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, -\timelineheight);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -10pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -10pt);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -\timelineheight+15pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -\timelineheight+15pt);

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\startyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\startyear};

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\tlendyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\tlendyear};
    }

    \newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {##1};
        }

        \draw ($(year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \newcommand{\plainentry}[2]{% plainentry won't print date in the timeline
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{invisible-year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (invisible-year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {};
        }

        \draw ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{entry} = [%
            align=left,%
            text width=\entrycolumnwidth,%
            node distance=10mm,%
            anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{year} = [anchor=east]
        \tikzstyle{timelinerule} = [%
            draw,%
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{latex'}}},%
            postaction={decorate},%
            shorten >=0.4pt]

        \drawtimeline
}
{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \let\startyear\@undefined
    \let\tlendyear\@undefined
    \let\yearcolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\rulecolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\entrycolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\timelineheight\@undefined
    \let\entrycounter\@undefined
    \let\ifnodedefined\@undefined
    \let\ifnodeundefined\@undefined
    \let\drawtimeline\@undefined
    \let\entry\@undefined
}
\makeatother

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Start the poster itself
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \begin{columns}[t]                            % the [t] option aligns the column's content at the top
    \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}         % empty spacer column
    \begin{column}{\twocolwid}
      \begin{block}{Timeline}
          \begin{timeline}{1900}{1990}{2cm}{2.5cm}{5cm}{12cm}
            \entry{1903}{Wilbur and Orville Wright fly the first powered airplane}
            \entry{1914}{Assassination of Franz Ferdinand}
            \plainentry{1917}{The October Revolution}
            \entry{1928}{Discovery of Penicillin}
            \plainentry{1929}{Stock Market Crash of 1929}
            \entry{1941}{Attack on Pearl Harbor}
            \plainentry{1944}{D-Day}
            \entry{1945}{The Bombing of Hiroshima}
            \plainentry{1947}{Creation of Israel as a Jewish State}
            \entry{1963}{US president John F. Kennedy assassinated in Dallas}
            \entry{1969}{The Moon Landing}
            \plainentry{1989}{Fall of the Berlin Wall}
        \end{timeline}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}         % empty spacer column
    \begin{column}{\twocolwid}\end{column}      % create a two-column-wide column and then 
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Why does the line all start from the same initial point? Does it have to do with the document size difference?

I would really appreciate it if you could help. Thanks a lot!

Edited:
Added `\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning, backgrounds}` and the initial points for each year is correct but the content attached to years are overlapping each other

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show your used short compilable TeX code in your question?

Comment: @Mensch Hello! Thanks for letting me know. I updated my post with the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`beamerposter` scales up the default font size, which makes the hardcoded absolute lengths in `timeline` env inappropriate.

The following changes seem to work:

```
@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@
 \usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
 \usepackage{graphicx}           % allows us to import images
 \usepackage{tikz}
+\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning, backgrounds}
 
 %-----------------------------------------------------------
 % Define the column width and poster size
@@ -114,8 +115,8 @@
     \begin{tikzpicture}
         \tikzstyle{entry} = [%
             align=left,%
-            text width=\entrycolumnwidth,%
-            node distance=10mm,%
+            text width=2\entrycolumnwidth,%
+            node distance=2*10mm,%
             anchor=west]
         \tikzstyle{year} = [anchor=east]
         \tikzstyle{timelinerule} = [%
@@ -152,7 +153,7 @@
     \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}         % empty spacer column
     \begin{column}{\twocolwid}
       \begin{block}{Timeline}
-          \begin{timeline}{1900}{1990}{2cm}{2.5cm}{5cm}{12cm}
+          \begin{timeline}{1900}{1990}{2cm}{2.5cm}{5cm}{24cm}
             \entry{1903}{Wilbur and Orville Wright fly the first powered airplane}
             \entry{1914}{Assassination of Franz Ferdinand}
             \plainentry{1917}{The October Revolution}
```

Full example

```tex
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter}
\usepackage{graphicx}           % allows us to import images
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, decorations.markings, positioning, backgrounds}

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Define the column width and poster size
% To set effective sepwid, onecolwid and twocolwid values, first choose how many columns you want and how much separation you want between columns
% The separation I chose is 0.024 and I want 4 columns
% Then set onecolwid to be (1-(4+1)*0.024)/4 = 0.22
% Set twocolwid to be 2*onecolwid + sepwid = 0.464
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\newlength{\sepwid}
\newlength{\onecolwid}
\newlength{\twocolwid}
\newlength{\threecolwid}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{48in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{36in}
\setlength{\sepwid}{0.024\paperwidth}
\setlength{\onecolwid}{0.22\paperwidth}
\setlength{\twocolwid}{0.464\paperwidth}
\setlength{\threecolwid}{0.708\paperwidth}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.5in}
\usepackage{exscale}

%==============================================================================
% build the poster timeline
%==============================================================================

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{timeline}[6]{

    \newcommand{\startyear}{#1}
    \newcommand{\tlendyear}{#2}

    \newcommand{\yearcolumnwidth}{#3}
    \newcommand{\rulecolumnwidth}{#4}
    \newcommand{\entrycolumnwidth}{#5}
    \newcommand{\timelineheight}{#6}

    \newcommand{\templength}{}

    \newcommand{\entrycounter}{0}

    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/85528/checking-whether-or-not-a-node-has-been-previously-defined
    % https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined
    \long\def\ifnodedefined##1##2##3{%
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@##1}{##3}{##2}%
    }

    \newcommand{\ifnodeundefined}[2]{%
        \ifnodedefined{##1}{}{##2}
    }

    \newcommand{\drawtimeline}{%
        \draw[timelinerule] (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, 0pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+5pt, -\timelineheight);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -10pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -10pt);
        \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+0pt, -\timelineheight+15pt) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+10pt, -\timelineheight+15pt);

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\startyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\startyear};

        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
        \node[year] (year-\tlendyear) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {\tlendyear};
    }

    \newcommand{\entry}[2]{%
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {##1};
        }

        \draw ($(year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \newcommand{\plainentry}[2]{% plainentry won't print date in the timeline
        % #1 is the year
        % #2 is the entry text

        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\lastentrycount}{\entrycounter}
        \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\entrycounter}{\entrycounter + 1}

        \ifdim \lastentrycount pt > 0 pt%
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) [below of=entry-\lastentrycount] {##2};
        \else%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(\startyear, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \node[entry] (entry-\entrycounter) at (\yearcolumnwidth+\rulecolumnwidth+10pt, \templength) {##2};
        \fi

        \ifnodeundefined{invisible-year-##1}{%
            \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\templength}{neg(add(multiply(subtract(##1, \startyear), divide(subtract(\timelineheight, 25), subtract(\tlendyear, \startyear))), 10))}
            \draw (\yearcolumnwidth+2.5pt, \templength) -- (\yearcolumnwidth+7.5pt, \templength);
            \node[year] (invisible-year-##1) at (\yearcolumnwidth, \templength) {};
        }

        \draw ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(2.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(invisible-year-##1.east)+(7.5pt, 0pt)$) -- ($(entry-\entrycounter.west)-(5pt,0)$) -- (entry-\entrycounter.west);
    }

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tikzstyle{entry} = [%
            align=left,%
            text width=2\entrycolumnwidth,%
            node distance=2*10mm,%
            anchor=west]
        \tikzstyle{year} = [anchor=east]
        \tikzstyle{timelinerule} = [%
            draw,%
            decoration={markings, mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=1.5]{latex'}}},%
            postaction={decorate},%
            shorten >=0.4pt]

        \drawtimeline
}
{
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \let\startyear\@undefined
    \let\tlendyear\@undefined
    \let\yearcolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\rulecolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\entrycolumnwidth\@undefined
    \let\timelineheight\@undefined
    \let\entrycounter\@undefined
    \let\ifnodedefined\@undefined
    \let\ifnodeundefined\@undefined
    \let\drawtimeline\@undefined
    \let\entry\@undefined
}
\makeatother

%-----------------------------------------------------------
% Start the poster itself
%-----------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
  \begin{columns}[t]                            % the [t] option aligns the column's content at the top
    \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}         % empty spacer column
    \begin{column}{\twocolwid}
      \begin{block}{Timeline}
          \begin{timeline}{1900}{1990}{2cm}{2.5cm}{5cm}{24cm}
            \entry{1903}{Wilbur and Orville Wright fly the first powered airplane}
            \entry{1914}{Assassination of Franz Ferdinand}
            \plainentry{1917}{The October Revolution}
            \entry{1928}{Discovery of Penicillin}
            \plainentry{1929}{Stock Market Crash of 1929}
            \entry{1941}{Attack on Pearl Harbor}
            \plainentry{1944}{D-Day}
            \entry{1945}{The Bombing of Hiroshima}
            \plainentry{1947}{Creation of Israel as a Jewish State}
            \entry{1963}{US president John F. Kennedy assassinated in Dallas}
            \entry{1969}{The Moon Landing}
            \plainentry{1989}{Fall of the Berlin Wall}
        \end{timeline}
      \end{block}
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{\sepwid}\end{column}         % empty spacer column
    \begin{column}{\twocolwid}\end{column}      % create a two-column-wide column and then 
 \end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: What is the **@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@** stuff?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner It's part of a [git-diff format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529441/how-to-read-the-output-from-git-diff).  Here `@@ -2,6 +2,7 @@` means in old file, start with line 2, the following 6 lines, including the lines start with `-` are; in new file, start with line 2, the following 7 lines, including the lines start with `+` are.