# Dectect if using \tikzmark or \tikzmarknode

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikzmark

I would like to be able to detect if a particular mark was made with

- `\tikzmark` (which requires the use of `pic cs:`) or if it was made with
- `\tikzmarknode` (which requires that `pic cs:` is *not* used).

Below is a contrived example which draws between two points: one created with `\tikzmark` and the other created with `\tikzmarknode`. Currently the first case works as the `\DrawPicture` invokes the first coordinate with `pic cs:` and the second one with out the `pic cs:`.

Question: How do I change the `\DrawPicture` macro so that *both* `\DrawPicture{MarkA}{MarkB}` and `\DrawPicture{MarkB}{MarkA}` (with the two marks reversed) will work?

I has orginally thought that using `\iftikzmark` would solve this problem, but seems that `\iftikzmark` only works as I expected on the second run, not the first run (even though the drawing code is invoked after the `\tikzmark` and `\tikzmarknode`. Even then, `\tikzmarknode` also creates a `\tikzmark`, so not really appropriate here to detect between the two cases.

#### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand*{\DrawPicture}[2]{%
    \par#1: \iftikzmark{#1}{tikzmark}{tikzmarknode}%
    \par#2: \iftikzmark{#2}{tikzmark}{tikzmarknode}%
    %% -------------
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \draw [ultra thick, red, -] (pic cs:#1) to[out=120, in=50, distance=1cm]  (#2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\begin{document}
\[
    \tikzmark{MarkA} a + \tikzmarknode{MarkB}{b}
\]

 \DrawPicture{MarkA}{MarkB}%  <-- This works.
%\DrawPicture{MarkB}{MarkA}%  <-- Want this also to be able to work

\end{document}
```

Comment: Looks like checking using [How can I knoed is a node is already defined](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37709/4301) seems to work, but wondering if there is a way to actually check if the `\node` was creatd by `\tikzmarknode`, or just `\node`. Altough, that may not actually matter though in this case.

Comment: I have a solution that works for this test case, but not in my actual use case. So, thinking that there is probably a more robust way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are quite a few edge cases here so the best solution will depend on what you want to happen in these situations.  To understand the edge cases, it's worth looking at what a tikzmark and tikzmarknode are.  (I'm sure the OP knows this, so this is partially for the wider audience.)

A tikzmark records the location of a point on the page.  To do this, it must write something to the aux file which is read in on the next compilation.  It *must* work this way because its position can only be known after shipout.

A node records its anchors relative to its origin in the current tikzpicture.  If that picture has the `remember picture` key set, then that origin is remembered using essentially the same underlying mechanism as a tikzmark.  In particular, although the node's relative position is available straightaway then to actually use its position on the page requires an additional compilation.  However, the node information is only available after the node has been defined in the current compilation (the tikzmark package does provide a way around that, but I view that as orthogonal to this discussion).

A tikzmarknode combines these two so that both the node's anchors are available in the usual way and the origin (of the coordinate system in which the node is defined) is available as a tikzmark.

So the only difference between a tikzmarknode and a regular node is in how the information is made available.  It is also not very difficult to set up all the information available from a tikzmarknode using other commands.

So the edge cases are:

1. A tikzmarknode is defined, but the test is run prior to its definition in the document. So at this point, the only information available is that of the tikzmark and not of the node.  What should the test do in this case?
2. A tikzmark is defined, and an unrelated node is defined with the same name.  What should the test do in this case?
3. A tikzmark and node are defined so that they are related as if defined via a tikzmarknode, just not with the exact `\tikzmarknode` command.  What should the test do in this case?

On the basis that the simplest is usually the best until it breaks, here's my first go at this.  It uses the same underlying information as in Jasper's first answer: testing `save@pt@<name>` and `pgf@sh@ns@<name>`.  The main difference is that rather than nesting the tests I keep them separate.  This way, I can test for four options:

1. Both true: tikzmarknode
2. `save@pt@<name>` true but `pgf@sh@ns@<name>` false: tikzmark
3. `save@pt@<name>` false but `pgf@sh@ns@<name@` true: node
4. Both false: undefined

In the following code then I have it wrapped in a classification function, but it would be simple to make it a genuine conditional - this is really me testing the waters to see what you actually want.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702241/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \l__tikzmark_is_a_tikzmark_bool
\bool_new:N \l__tikzmark_is_a_node_bool

\DeclareDocumentCommand \ClassifyNode {m}
{
  \bool_set:Nn \l__tikzmark_is_a_tikzmark_bool
  {
    \tl_if_exist_p:c {save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}
  }
  \bool_set:Nn \l__tikzmark_is_a_node_bool
  {
    \tl_if_exist_p:c {pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name{#1}}
  }
  Mark~#1~is~
  \bool_if:nTF
  {
    \l__tikzmark_is_a_tikzmark_bool
    ||
    \l__tikzmark_is_a_node_bool
  }
  {
    a~
    \bool_if:NT \l__tikzmark_is_a_tikzmark_bool {tikzmark}
    \bool_if:NT \l__tikzmark_is_a_node_bool {node}
  }
  {
    not~ (yet)~ defined
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\ClassifyNode{A}\par
\ClassifyNode{B}\par
\ClassifyNode{C}

\tikzmark{A}

\ClassifyNode{A}\par
\ClassifyNode{B}\par
\ClassifyNode{C}

\tikzmarknode{B}{B}

\ClassifyNode{A}\par
\ClassifyNode{B}\par
\ClassifyNode{C}

\tikz {\node (C) {C};}

\ClassifyNode{A}\par
\ClassifyNode{B}\par
\ClassifyNode{C}

\end{document}
```

On first run this outputs:

```
Mark A is not (yet) defined
Mark B is not (yet) defined
Mark C is not (yet) defined

Mark A is not (yet) defined
Mark B is not (yet) defined
Mark C is not (yet) defined
B
Mark A is not (yet) defined
Mark B is a node
Mark C is not (yet) defined
C
Mark A is not (yet) defined
Mark B is a node
Mark C is a node
```

On subsequent runs, this changes to:

```
Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmark
Mark C is not (yet) defined

Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmark
Mark C is not (yet) defined
B
Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmarknode
Mark C is not (yet) defined
C
Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmarknode
Mark C is a node
```

In terms of *using* the coordinates, this seems the correct behaviour as it tells you what can be used at each stage.  So the fact that `B` is a tikzmarknode is irrelevant prior to its definition: you can only use that fact afterwards.

---

*Update: 7/12/2023*

Here's how to use `tikzmark`'s `save node` facility to make it possible to classify a `\tikzmarknode` correctly even before it is defined.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/702241/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

\bool_new:N \l__tikzmark_is_a_tikzmark_bool
\bool_new:N \l__tikzmark_is_a_node_bool

\DeclareDocumentCommand \ClassifyNode {m}
{
  \bool_set:Nn \l__tikzmark_is_a_tikzmark_bool
  {
    \tl_if_exist_p:c {save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}
  }
  \bool_set:Nn \l__tikzmark_is_a_node_bool
  {
    \tl_if_exist_p:c {pgf@sh@ns@\tikz@pp@name{#1}}
  }
  Mark~#1~is~
  \bool_if:nTF
  {
    \l__tikzmark_is_a_tikzmark_bool
    ||
    \l__tikzmark_is_a_node_bool
  }
  {
    a~
    \bool_if:NT \l__tikzmark_is_a_tikzmark_bool {tikzmark}
    \bool_if:NT \l__tikzmark_is_a_node_bool {node}
  }
  {
    not~ (yet)~ defined
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother

\NewDocumentCommand \ClassifyNodes {}
{
  \ClassifyNode{A}\par
  \ClassifyNode{B}\par
  \ClassifyNode{C}\par
  \ClassifyNode{D}
}

\tikzset{
  save nodes to file,
  restore nodes from file
}

\begin{document}

\ClassifyNodes

\tikzmark{A}

\ClassifyNodes

\tikzmarknode{B}{B}

\ClassifyNodes

\tikzmarknode{C}{C}
\SaveNode{C}

\ClassifyNodes

\tikz {\node (D) {D};}

\ClassifyNodes

\end{document}
```

This stabilises to:

```
Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmark
Mark C is a tikzmarknode
Mark D is not (yet) defined

Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmark
Mark C is a tikzmarknode
Mark D is not (yet) defined
B
Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmarknode
Mark C is a tikzmarknode
Mark D is not (yet) defined
C
Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmarknode
Mark C is a tikzmarknode
Mark D is not (yet) defined
D
Mark A is a tikzmark
Mark B is a tikzmarknode
Mark C is a tikzmarknode
Mark D is a node
```

---

*Update: 2023-12-10* One of the issues with combining `save node` with a `\tikzmarknode` is that my code to save a node requires two steps: one which adds a node name to a list and another that processes that list and stores the node details in some location.  When using this in a tikzpicture, the first step is usually invoked on the node itself and then the second happens at the end of the picture.  This needs (at least) two keys: one on the tikzpicture that installs the end-of-picture code, and one on each node to be saved.

A `\tikzmarknode` only provides immediate access to the options on its node, to get at the surrounding tikzpicture requires using the `every tikzmarknode picture` style, such as:

```
\tikzset{every tikzmarknode picture/.style={save nodes to file}}
\tikzmarknode%
[save node]
{C}{C}
```

but that hooks into *every* `\tikzmarknode`.  While it's safe to do so (the saving node code only executes if there are nodes to save), I'm not overly happy about needing to do that if only wanting to save one or two nodes.

But `\tikzmarknode`s are quite simple compared to general tikzpictures so we can hook in after the node has been defined rather than waiting until the picture finishes.  So here's a key that seems to work, and if it genuinely does then I'll add it to the `tikzmark` library.

```
\ExplSyntaxOn
\tikzset{
  save~ tikzmarknode/.code={
    \tikz_fig_must_be_named:
    \pgfkeysalso{
      append~ after~ command={
        \pgfextra{
          \clist_gput_right:Nv \g__sn_nodes_clist {tikz@last@fig@name}
          \maybe_save_nodes:
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

...

\tikzmarknode%
[save tikzmarknode]
{C}{C}
```

Comment: This seems to be more or less what I also had in the beginning. The problem was then that the OP wanted to get the right definitions already upon the first run if the check is done after the definitions. (And the OP also wanted that everything was right after no more than two runs.)

Comment: Yes, this was really an extended comment with a request for clarification about the edge cases. I don't understand why it would be useful to know that B is a tikzmarknode without being able to make use of that fact.

Comment: in particular, I'm always happy to extend the tikzmark codebase, and your code looks great for that, but only if I can see why it is useful.

Comment: It would be great if one could somehow "legally" hook into every `\tikzmark` and every `\tikzmarknode` and grab the current node name. I am unsure what other use cases there could be (here it is to know after the first run already that some name belongs to a `\tikzmark` or `\tikzmarknode`), but currently this seems only to be possible using keys that are probably not meant for such things. But maybe I am wrong and this already works: `every tikzmarknode` looks like a great candidate, but I fail to pass the current node name to it or process it.

Comment: But you are right, what the OP asked could also be merely an XY question that can be better solved with a different approach. As far as I understand, it is about the use of `pic cs:` or not in a subsequent `tikzpicture`.

Comment: One possible extension to the code would be to change the invocation of `every tikzmarknode`  to `every tikzmarknode/.try=<name>`.  That way, you would have access to the tikzmark(node)'s name inside that code.

Comment: At the start of the second run `Mark B` is determined to be a tikzmark, even though it is a `\tikznode`.  This seems to me that I can only safely attempt to use `\tikzmark` before it is defined.  But, if I don't know if it is a `\tikzmark`/`\tikzmarknode`, then have to wait until after they are defined so that you can properly set up the coordinate.  I will post what I am using which I hope addresses the other comments.

Comment: @PeterGrill I'm still unclear what behaviour you would like at a point in the document before the tikzmarknode is defined. At this juncture then only the associated tikzmark is available, so the fact that it is defined by a tikzmarknode is useless to you because you can't do anything with that information. This was the whole point of separating out the tikzmark from tikzmarknode originally. If you want to use the node data prior to its definition then the `save node` facility might be useful.

Comment: @PeterGrill See edit

Comment: @AndrewStacey: Thanks, was having issues with figuring out hot ot use `save node`. But, am getting an `Undefined control sequence. \pgf@sh@pi@current bounding box ->\pgfpictureid`. I haven't updated in a while, so perhaps I am out of date on some pacakge.

Comment: @PeterGrill no, that's a bug in the current version but I think it can be safely ignored.

Comment: @PeterGrill See edit

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether this can help in your specific context, but expanding on [this answer you link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/37709/4301) you could test for two things (`#1` being the node name):

1. A picture has been saved:
   `\@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}` should be `false`.
2. It is a `\node`: `\@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}` should be `false`.

If 1) is false, it is not just a regular Ti*k*Z node. Else, if 2) is false, it is a `\tikzmarknode` and  not just a `\tikzmark`.

Using `\tikzmark@pp@name` in the first test, we additionally check whether the saved picture was created by `tikzmark` or `tikzmarknode`. Testing agaist the name of a node created using `\node[remember picture]` would still return `true`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\IsTikzmarkNode}[1]{
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{
        node
    } {
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{
            tikzmark
        } {
            tikzmarknode
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

% A is a tikzmark
foo\tikzmark{A} bar

% B is a tikzmarknode
\tikzmarknode{B}{foo}

% C is a node
\tikz{\node (C) {bar};}

\bigskip

\IsTikzmarkNode{A}

\IsTikzmarkNode{B}

\IsTikzmarkNode{C}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In case you wonder (because I did): `\@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@\tikzmark@pp@name{C}}` will be `false` if `\node (C) {};` is defined and even if this test takes place outside the `\tikz` scope.

---

In the above example, you could simply do (without additionally testing whether it is just a regular node):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\IsTikzmarkNode}{ m }{
    \@ifundefined{save@pt@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{
        -1
    } {
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{
            0
        } {
            1
        }
    }
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\DrawPicture}[2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture]
        \ifnum\IsTikzmarkNode{#1} > 0\relax
            \coordinate (start) at (#1);
        \else
            \coordinate (start) at (pic cs:#1);    
        \fi
        \ifnum\IsTikzmarkNode{#2} > 0\relax
            \coordinate (end) at (#2);
        \else
            \coordinate (end) at (pic cs:#2);    
        \fi
        \draw [ultra thick, red] (start) to[bend left=90] (end);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\begin{document}
\[
    \tikzmark{MarkA} a + \tikzmarknode{MarkB}{b}
\]

 \DrawPicture{MarkA}{MarkB}%  <-- This works.
 \DrawPicture{MarkB}{MarkA}%  <-- Want this also to be able to work

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Okay, this took me a while, but I think I got what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l_istikzmarknode_registeredmarks_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\RegisterTikzmark}{ m }{
    \seq_gpush:Nn \l_istikzmarknode_registeredmarks_seq { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IsRegisteredTikzmarkTF}{ m m m }{
    \seq_if_in:NnTF \l_istikzmarknode_registeredmarks_seq { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
}
\seq_new:N \l_istikzmarknode_registerednodes_seq
\NewDocumentCommand{\RegisterTikzmarkNode}{ m }{
    \seq_gpush:Nn \l_istikzmarknode_registerednodes_seq { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\IsRegisteredTikzmarkNodeTF}{ m m m }{
    \seq_if_in:NnTF \l_istikzmarknode_registerednodes_seq { #1 } { #2 } { #3 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    save picture id/.append code={
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\RegisterTikzmark{#1}}
        \RegisterTikzmark{#1}
    },
    register tikzmarknode/.code={
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\RegisterTikzmarkNode{#1}}
        \RegisterTikzmarkNode{#1}
    },
    maybe define node/.append style={
        register tikzmarknode={#1}
    }
}

\newcommand*{\IsTikzmarkNode}[1]{
    \IsRegisteredTikzmarkTF{#1}{
        \IsRegisteredTikzmarkNodeTF{#1}{
            tikzmarknode
        } {
            tikzmark
        }
    } {
        \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}{
            undefined
        } {
            node 
        }
    }  
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    
    \IsTikzmarkNode{A}
    
    \IsTikzmarkNode{B}
    
    \IsTikzmarkNode{C}
    
    \bigskip
    
    % A is a tikzmark
    foo\tikzmark{A} bar
    
    % B is a tikzmarknode
    \tikzmarknode{B}{foo}
    
    % C is a node
    \tikz{\node (C) {bar};}
    
    \bigskip
    
    \IsTikzmarkNode{A}
    
    \IsTikzmarkNode{B}
    
    \IsTikzmarkNode{C}
    
\end{document}
```

This will output after the first run:

[image]

And after every following run:

[image]

What does it do? First, I define two sequences `\l_istikzmarknode_registeredmarks_seq` and `\l_istikzmarknode_registerednodes_seq` where I store all the `\tikzmark`s and `\tikzmarknode`s. There might be other ways to directly grab this information from the PGF code. Anyways, this solution also works with node names containing spaces or dashes.

Then, I append some code to `save picture id` that is actually called for every `\tikzmark` (and also for every `\tikzmarknode`) and store the names of the `\tikzmark`s in the sequence `\l_istikzmarknode_registeredmarks_seq`. I can use this later to test whether a string is a name of a defined `\tikzmark`. I also store the command to store the name into the sequence in the .aux file, so that is being called on the second run.

Then, similarly to above, I append some code to the style `maybe define node` that is executed for every `\tikzmarknodes` and takes the name of the node as argument. I store these name in the sequence `\l_istikzmarknode_registerednodes_seq`. I can use this later to test whether a string is a name of a defined `\tikzmarknode`. Again, I also store the command to store the name into the sequence in the .aux file.

Now, I just need to check whether the given name is in one of the two sequences and, for regular `\nodes`, additionally for `\@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@\tikzmark@pp@name{#1}}`.

---

I am not 100% sure, but it might be semantically cleaner to replace

```
register tikzmarknode/.code={
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\RegisterTikzmarkNode{#1}}
    \RegisterTikzmarkNode{#1}
},
maybe define node/.append style={
    register tikzmarknode={#1}
}
```

by

```
every tikzmarknode/.code={
    \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\RegisterTikzmarkNode{\tikz@id@name}}
    \RegisterTikzmarkNode{\tikz@id@name}
}
```

in the above code. But somehow, the test does not work right after the first run then.

Comment: That looks good, but fails if the `\IsTikzmarkNode{}` is exectued _before_ the marks/nodes are placed. On 1st run all three are reported as `nodes`, and on 2nd run, `B` is reported as a `\tikzmark`. `A` and `C` are correctly identified on 2nd run.

Comment: @PeterGrill Hm, I am unsure how we could detect this though. With "before" you mean that `\IsTikzmarkNode{}` is place before `\tikzmark(node)` in the code even?

Comment: Yes that is what I meant, the test should work before they are placed.  On first run, they should be reported as undefined (not `nodes`) when tested _before_ they are defined. 2nd run should identify them correctly, even before they are defined.

Comment: Yes, run twice (for the test _before_ definition). Ideally, should identify correctly the first time if for the test that is run after definition.

Comment: @PeterGrill I think, I got it. Check my edit (I deleted some of my prior tries as these are essentially included in the final version).

Comment: Thanks for all your help in this issue. It got me got me going in the direction I needed to resolve my particular issue.

Answer (score 1):

My goal is to code drawing macros that could accept marks made by either `\tikzmark` or with `\tikzmarknode` *without* tagging each mark as to how it was created, or knowing whether they were defined yet or not. If they were not defined I could

- either not to the drawing, or
- use `(0,0)` for the coordinate so there was a visible indicator that another run was clearly needed.

The solution I am using is below (commented out the portion needed for the produced diagram, but not essential to following the code). Any feedback on potential problems with this approach would be helpful.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfStrContains}[4]{%
    \StrPosition{#1}{#2}[\@@Position]% Record position in \@@Position
    \IfEq{\@@Position}{0}%
        {#4}% \@@Position=0 => Did not find the target string
        {#3}% \@@Position>0 => Found the target string
}%
\newcommand{\IfNodeDefined}[3]{%
    %% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/37709/how-can-i-know-if-a-node-is-already-defined
    % #1 = node name
    % #2 = code to execute if node is defined
    % #3 = code to execute if node is NOT yet defined
    \@ifundefined{pgf@sh@ns@#1}{#3}{#2}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\DefineTikzmarkCoordinate}{%
    %% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/702241/dectect-if-using-tikzmark-or-tikzmarknode
    m%% #1 = name of coordinate
    m%% #2 = \tikzmark name, or \tikzmarknode name
}{%
    %%% #1 maybe of the form "<node name>.<anchor>" so remove text after the .
    \IfStrContains{#2}{.}{%
        \StrBefore{#2}{.}[\@@TikzmarkName]%
    }{%
        \def\@@TikzmarkName{#2}%
    }%
    \IfNodeDefined{\@@TikzmarkName}{% we need to access this as a node
        \coordinate (#1) at (#2);
    }{%
        \iftikzmark{\@@TikzmarkName}{% need to use the 'pic cs' coordinate system
            \coordinate (#1) at (pic cs:#2);
        }{% not defined, so use the origin
            \coordinate (#1) at (0,0);
        }%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\newcommand*{\DrawPicture}[3][]{%
    %% -------------
    \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
        \DefineTikzmarkCoordinate{Coordinate 1}{#2}%
        \DefineTikzmarkCoordinate{Coordinate 2}{#3}%
        %% -------
        \draw [ultra thick, -, #1] 
            (Coordinate 1) to[out=120, in=50, distance=1cm]  (Coordinate 2);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\begin{document}
%\begin{minipage}{0.5\linewidth}
%The following figure has
%\begin{itemize}
%\item
%    \verb|\tikzmark| to the left of $a$ and
%\item
%    $b$ has a \verb|\tikzmarknode| around it.
%\end{itemize}
%\end{minipage}
%\begin{minipage}{0.3\linewidth}
\[
    \tikzmark{MarkA} a + \tikzmarknode{MarkB}{b}
\]
\DrawPicture[red, -latex]{MarkA}{MarkB.north}%             <-- This works.
\DrawPicture[blue,-latex, yscale=-1]{MarkB.south}{MarkA}%  <-- Now, this also to work
%\end{minipage}
%
%\medskip
%The macro \verb|\DrawPicture| can draw between these two in either direction.
\end{document}
```